# Skrollr elements with same anchor target and animation execute at different time

Tags: html, css, anchor, delay, skrollr

I have a background div that fills the whole screen and a bar in the header and they are supposed to animate background colour at the same time. They both have the exact same inline skrollr animation, for example

```
<div class="profile_bg animation_03" data-anchor-target="#raising-profile" data--400-bottom-top="background-color:rgb(253, 234, 237); opacity:1;" data-400-top-top="background-color:rgb(255, 248, 201); opacity:1;"></div>
```

and

```
<div class="grey-mask animation_03" data-anchor-target="#raising-profile" data--400-bottom-top="background-color:rgb(253, 234, 237); opacity:1;" data-400-top-top="background-color:rgb(255, 248, 201); opacity:1;"></div>
```

but .grey-mask executes slightly later than the background div. Why could that happen?  Has it got anything to do with position:absolute of 3 overlapping skrollr elements (.grey-mask)? Here is the link to the issue http://bit.ly/1zaZfCY

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any difference in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. If you scroll up and down fast, you should see that there is a 40px high bar under the grey bar at the very top of the page that changes colour a little bit later than the background colour. You should notice it by looking at the right hand side of the big images.

Comment: You're right. Could be a bug in the smooth-scrolling implementation or simply the browser updating the styles differently.

Comment: Do you know if there is a solution for that..?

Comment: How could I? I don't even know the cause.

Comment: So you think that it has nothing to do with the plugin itself and I should look elsewhere? Thank you anyway

Comment: I said that it could be a bug as well.